# in R, check if 1 appears in a row (in any of the selected column)

Tags: r, dataframe

The data is binary. I need to code something that checks if any of the selected columns is a 1 and populates a new column with this information.

I do not want it to check all the columns in the dataframe only the specified ones by name.

Let's pretend the columns of interest are: are question1, smoker and drinker

I have:

```
Subject    question1 question2   smoker  drinker 
   A          1          0          0        1             
   B          0          1          0        0          
   C          0          0          0        0
```

I want:

```
Subject    question1 question2  smoker  drinker   q1_smoker_or_drinker
   A          1          0          0        1         1             
   B          0          1          0        0         0            
   C          0          0          0        0         0
```

I tried:

```
list1<- c('Subject', 'question1','smoker','drinker')
newdata <- data_scored[, list1]
grepl("1", newdata[2:4])
```

But the return is a vector with boolean values and I was unable to merge this into the full data as a column.

I know this should be very simple but somehow I am having trouble making this.
 Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `as.numeric(apply(newdata[2:4], 1, function(x) any(x == 1)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "or" operator, `|`. It works fine here because R will treat 1 as true and 0 as false:

```
> df
  Subject question1 question2 smoker drinker
1       A         1         0      0       1
2       B         0         1      0       0
3       C         0         0      0       0
> df$q1_smoke_drink = df$question1 | df$smoker | df$drinker 
> df
  Subject question1 question2 smoker drinker q1_smoke_drink
1       A         1         0      0       1           TRUE
2       B         0         1      0       0          FALSE
3       C         0         0      0       0          FALSE
```

When you don't have 1's and 0's `|` would still work fine, you would just need to be a bit more explicit about the condition, e.g.

```
(df$question3 == "a") | (df$question4 == "b")
```

Comment: `rowSums(df[-1])>0`

Comment: @Onyambu I prefer code that is semantically meaningful where possible, and I think my code reads pretty clearly as "check if Q1, smoker, OR drinker are 1", but feel free to post that as a separate answer.